# Is the Arrested Development movie really being made?

Tags: arrested-development

At the risk of provoking nothing but speculation, I was wondering if there is any definite proof as to whether the long-awaited Arrested Development movie will be made. Usually each time I check every few months there is a new hopeful promise, which only seems to serve to displace the previous hopeful promise.

The [current story](http://www.ifc.com/fix/2012/01/arrested-development-movie-update) is that there will be 10 episodes followed by a movie, shooting this summer to be released early next year. I'm not really savvy to the way these productions happen; is there any solid evidence that these plans will be carried out? Or is the whole thing just a giant pun on the show's name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [TheFilmStage](http://thefilmstage.com/news/arrested-development-movie-coming-after-10-episode-fourth-season-early-2013-released-planned/);

> *Jason Bateman then confirmed on Twitter that they will shoot 10 episodes and the movie will follow. He expects an early 2013 release, but the network on where these initial episodes will air, or the studio that will produce/distribute, haven’t been locked down either. Hurwitz said they don’t own the property outright and “there is still lots of business to do” and the logistics of having a studio working on a film and TV series simultaneously is difficult.*

However, I expect this is the same report you have seen yourself, and is as concrete as the evidence gets at the moment.

Comment: I saw him on daily show recently and he said they are trying to make it, but can not confirm or deny anything yet.